# Manage products error processing (report included)

Tags: magento-1.9, error, products-management

I was recently disabling products in magento, i refresh to find that this comes up inside the admin panel:

There has been an error processing your request. Everything else inside the admin panel is working. I've checked var/reports and this is the last file in there:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:953:"SELECT `e`.*, `at_qty`.`qty`, `at_status`.`value` AS `status`, `at_visibility`.`value` AS `visibility`, `at_name`.`value` AS `name` FROM `sc5cymvir_catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 LEFT JOIN `sc5cymvir_cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `at_qty` ON (at_qty.`product_id`=e.entity_id) AND (at_qty.stock_id=1)
 INNER JOIN `sc5cymvir_catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status` ON (`at_status`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_status`.`attribute_id` = '96') AND (`at_status`.`store_id` = 0)
 INNER JOIN `sc5cymvir_catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_visibility` ON (`at_visibility`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_visibility`.`attribute_id` = '102') AND (`at_visibility`.`store_id` = 0)
 INNER JOIN `sc5cymvir_catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_name` ON (`at_name`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_name`.`attribute_id` = '71') AND (`at_name`.`store_id` = 0) WHERE (at_name.value LIKE '%Blue%') ORDER BY `e`.`category_ids` ASC LIMIT 200

";i:1;s:7271:"#0 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `e`.*, `...', Array)
#4 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `e`.*, `...', Array)
#5 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `e`.*, `...', Array)
#6 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(734): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT `e`.*, `...', Array)
#7 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(1045): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT `e`.*, `...')
#8 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(871): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->_loadEntities(false, false)
#9 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(533): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->load()
#10 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php(125): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#11 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(626): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#12 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(632): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareGrid()
#13 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(918): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_beforeToHtml()
#14 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('grid', true)
#16 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product.php(79): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('grid')
#17 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product.phtml(46): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product->getGridHtml()
#18 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/homepages/34/d...')
#19 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#20 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#21 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#22 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Container.php(308): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#23 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container->_toHtml()
#24 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#25 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#26 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#27 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#28 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(74): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#29 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/homepages/34/d...')
#30 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#31 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#32 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#33 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#34 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#35 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#36 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(180): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#37 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->indexAction()
#38 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#39 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#40 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#41 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#42 /homepages/34/d614833542/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/naturalpet/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#43 {main}";s:3:"url";s:76:"/index.php/admin/catalog_product/index/key/636297d8c7caa215b53c0cef2d847784/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

[image: image of magento error]

If you can help that would be very much appreciated, my knowledge of Magento is not fantastic, I can usually get around with code, but i'm definitely not a coder. I'm using Magento 1.9.2

Answer (score 0):

Logged out and back in and it seems to be fine, very strange.